# How can I count occurrences with groupBy?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

I want to collect the items in a stream into a map which groups equal objects together, and maps to the number of occurrences.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Hello", "Hello", "World");
Map<String, Long> wordToFrequency = // what goes here?
```

So in this case, I would like the map to consist of these entries:

```
Hello -> 2
World -> 1
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 502, accepted):

I think you're just looking for the [overload](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) which takes another `Collector` to specify what to do with each group... and then `Collectors.counting()` to do the counting:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add("Hello");
        list.add("Hello");
        list.add("World");

        Map<String, Long> counted = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

        System.out.println(counted);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
{Hello=2, World=1}
```

(There's also the possibility of using `groupingByConcurrent` for more efficiency. Something to bear in mind for your real code, if it would be safe in your context.)

Comment: Perfect! ... from javadoc `and then performing a reduction operation on the values associated with a given key using the specified downstream Collector`

Comment: Using Function.identity() (with static import) instead of e -> e makes it a little nicer to read: 
Map<String, Long> counted = list.stream().collect(groupingBy(identity(), counting()));

Comment: Hello, I have another question, what if I want to show it in descending order?
If I have 4 World and 2 Hello and what to show them

{World=4, Hello=2}

Comment: @MichaelKors: If you have another question, you should ask it as a separate post, after performing appropriate research.

Answer (score 39):

Here is example for list of Objects

```
Map<String, Long> requirementCountMap = requirements.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Requirement::getRequirementType, Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 16):

Here are slightly different options to accomplish the task at hand.

using `toMap`:

```
list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), e -> 1, Math::addExact));
```

using `Map::merge`:

```
Map<String, Integer> accumulator = new HashMap<>();
list.forEach(s -> accumulator.merge(s, 1, Math::addExact));
```

Answer (score 13):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add("Hello");
list.add("Hello");
list.add("World");

Map<String, List<String>> collect = list.stream()
                                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o));
collect.entrySet()
       .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " - " + e.getValue().size()));
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is the simple solution by [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex):

```java
StreamEx.of(list).groupingBy(Function.identity(), MoreCollectors.countingInt());
```

This has the advantage of reducing the Java stream boilerplate code: `collect(Collectors.`

Comment: What's the reason to use it over Java8 streams?

Comment: @TorstenOjaperv The only real reason is that it's more concise (it reduces boilerplate).

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to using a third-party library, you can use the `Collectors2` class in [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections) to convert the `List` to a `Bag` using a `Stream`. A [`Bag`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/bag/Bag.html) is a data structure that is [built for counting](https://medium.com/oracledevs/bag-the-counter-2689e901aadb).

```
Bag<String> counted =
        list.stream().collect(Collectors2.countBy(each -> each));

Assert.assertEquals(1, counted.occurrencesOf("World"));
Assert.assertEquals(2, counted.occurrencesOf("Hello"));

System.out.println(counted.toStringOfItemToCount());
```

Output:

```
{World=1, Hello=2}
```

In this particular case, you can simply `collect` the `List` directly into a `Bag`.

```
Bag<String> counted = 
        list.stream().collect(Collectors2.toBag());
```

You can also create the `Bag` without using a `Stream` by adapting the `List` with the Eclipse Collections protocols.

```
Bag<String> counted = Lists.adapt(list).countBy(each -> each);
```

or in this particular case:

```
Bag<String> counted = Lists.adapt(list).toBag();
```

You could also just create the Bag directly.

```
Bag<String> counted = Bags.mutable.with("Hello", "Hello", "World");
```

A `Bag<String>` is like a `Map<String, Integer>` in that it internally keeps track of keys and their counts.  But, if you ask a `Map` for a key it doesn't contain, it will return `null`.  If you ask a `Bag` for a key it doesn't contain using `occurrencesOf`, it will return 0.

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.