# Counting elements of a Stream

Tags: java, count, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I want to count the different elements of a stream and am wondering why

```
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("a", "b", "a", "c", "c", "a", "a", "d");
Map<String, Integer> counter1 = stream.collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, 1, Integer::sum));
```

doesn't work. Eclipse tells me

> The method toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator) in the type Collectors is not applicable for the arguments (( s) -> {}, int, Integer::sum)

By the way, I know about that solution:

```
Map<String, Long> counter2 = stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()));
```

So I have two questions:

1. What is the mistake in my first approach?
2. How would you implement such a counter?

**EDIT:** I solved the first question by myself:

```
Map<String, Integer> counter1 = stream.collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> 1, Integer::sum));
```

Java is expecting a function as second argument.

Comment: If you solved the question by yourself, just write an answer instead of editing the question.

Comment: @TagirValeev It's only the first part. Isn't an answer supposed to answer the full question? I also want the people to no longer be concerning about telling me what I did wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441088/group-by-counting-in-java8-stream-api

Comment: @NitinDandriyal That's exactly the second approach.

Comment: If you need a `Map<String, Integer>`, you could use `.collect(groupingBy(s -> s, summingInt(s -> 1)));`, although the `counting()` approach is more readable.

Answer (score 13):

There are indeed several ways to do it.  The one you haven't mentioned is `.collect(groupingBy(x -> x, summingInt(x -> 1)));`

There are some differences in performance.

Approach #1 is going to be at its best if there are very few objects per bucket.  In the ideal case of only 1 object per bucket, you end up with the final map right away with no need to modify the entries.  In the worst case of having a very large number of repeated objects, it will have to do a lot of boxing/unboxing.

Approach #2 relies on `counting()` collector, which doesn't specify exactly how it should do the counting.  The current implementation forwards to `reducing` but that might change.

The `summingInt` approach will accumulate the count in `int` rather than `Integer` and thus will not require any boxing/unboxing.  It will be at its best if objects repeat a very large number of times.

As for which one to choose, it is best to code for clarity and optimize when it becomes necessary.  To me, `groupingBy(x->x, counting())` expresses the intent most clearly, so that's the one I would favor.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private Collector<CustomObject.class, int[], Integer> customIntegerCountingCollector() {
    return Collector.of(
        () -> new int[1],
        (result, ) -> result[0] += 1,
        (result1, result2) -> {
            result1[0] += result2[0];
            return result1;
        },
        total -> Integer.valueOf(total[0])
    );
}
```

Inspired by : https://www.deadcoderising.com/2017-03-07-java-8-creating-a-custom-collector-for-your-stream/

Answer (score -3):

The following should work if you are not using parallel streams:

```
final int[] counter = {0};
stream.peek(s -> counter[0]++);
```