# Most elegant solution to count elements of a Stream

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I asked already [a few months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451284/counting-elements-of-a-stream) how to count the elements of a Stream. My new approach is:

```
int count = stream.mapToInt(element -> 1).sum();
```

What is the most elegant solution in your opinion?

Comment: `stream.count()`

Comment: @Eran Why didn't tell me anybody seven months ago?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Be happy someone did now I guess

Comment: You asked something else in the linked question.

Comment: @J.Murray I'm very happy indeed, but surprised, too ;).

Comment: @Eran Thanks for pointing that out. You're right. It was a different question.

Comment: You know that there is something called [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html)? By the way, even without using it, IDEs suggest you available methods when proposing code completions…

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle's Documentation on Stream:

> **Reduction operations**
>
> A reduction operation (also called a fold) takes a sequence of input
>   elements and combines them into a single summary result by repeated
>   application of a combining operation, such as finding the sum or
>   maximum of a set of numbers, or accumulating elements into a list. The
>   streams classes have multiple forms of general reduction operations,
>   called reduce() and collect(), as well as multiple specialized
>   reduction forms such as sum(), max(), or **count()**.

You were using one of the reduction operations from stream, there just happens to be others as well