# Stream.collect(groupingBy(identity(), counting()) and then sort the result by value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I can [collect a list of words into a bag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441088/group-by-counting-in-java8-stream-api) (a.k.a. multi-set):

```
Map<String, Long> bag =
        Arrays.asList("one o'clock two o'clock three o'clock rock".split(" "))
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

However, the entries of the bag are not guaranteed to be in any particular order. For example,

```
{rock=1, o'clock=3, one=1, three=1, two=1}
```

I can put them into a list, and then sort them using my implementation of a value comparator:

```
ArrayList<Entry<String, Long>> list = new ArrayList<>(bag.entrySet());
Comparator<Entry<String, Long>> valueComparator = new Comparator<Entry<String, Long>>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<String, Long> e1, Entry<String, Long> e2) {
        return e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue());
    }
};
Collections.sort(list, valueComparator);
```

This gives the desired result:

```
[o'clock=3, rock=1, one=1, three=1, two=1]
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? I'm sure it's a problem many people must have solved. Is there something built into Java Streams API that I can use?

Comment: Check out Pattern.splitAsStream.

Comment: Thanks @Brian. I was unaware of the Pattern.splitAsStream method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to create a comparator, there is already one for this task: [`Map.Entry.comparingByValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue--). This creates a comparator that compares values of entry of a map. In this case, we are interested in their reverse order so we could have:

```
Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())
```

as the comparator. Your code could then become

```
Collections.sort(list, Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()));
```

without having the custom comparator.

---

To sort the resulting `Map` regarding its values, you could also use a Stream pipeline. Also, instead of calling `Stream.of(Arrays.asList("...").split(" "))`, you may want to call `Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream("...")` if you have long Strings to handle.

```
Map<String, Long> bag =
   Pattern.compile(" ")
          .splitAsStream("one o'clock two o'clock three o'clock rock")
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
Map<String, Long> sortedBag = 
    bag.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(
           Map.Entry::getKey,
           Map.Entry::getValue,
           (v1, v2) -> { throw new IllegalStateException(); },
           LinkedHashMap::new
       ));
```

This code creates a Stream of the entry of the map, sorts it in reverse order of the value and collects that into a `LinkedHashMap` to keep the encounter order.

Output:

```
{o'clock=3, rock=1, one=1, three=1, two=1}
```

---

Alternatively, you might look into the [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library, for which you could have:

```
Map<String, Long> bag =
    StreamEx.split("one o'clock two o'clock three o'clock rock", " ")
            .sorted()
            .runLengths()
            .reverseSorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .toCustomMap(LinkedHashMap::new);
```

This code sorts each String and then calls `runLengths()`. This method will collapse adjacent equal elements into a `Stream<String, Long>`  where the value is the number of times the elements appeared. For example, on the Stream `["foo", "foo", "bar"]`, this method would produce the Stream `[Entry("foo", 2), Entry("bar", 1)]`. Finally, this is sorted in descending order of the values and collected into a `LinkedHashMap`.

Note that this gives the correct result without having to do 2 distinct Stream pipelines.

Comment: Note that StreamEx solution (with runLengths) will likely to be slower on big inputs. It works best when data is already presorted (or you don't need the sorting). Explicit sorting steps is slower, according to my tests. On the other hand I optimized one-character regexps like `" "`, so the splitting via StreamEx would be faster.

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the second stream pipeline? The first bag is just an intermediate result that we don't need anyway.

Comment: @Roland The StreamEx solution runs in a single pipeline, but the creation of the intermediate map is really needed: to sort on the value of the map, all entries need to be present first.

Answer (score 4):

If you're open to using a third party library which has a `Bag` type built in then you can do the following using [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections):

```
Bag<String> bag =
    Bags.mutable.with("one o'clock two o'clock three o'clock rock".split(" "));
ListIterable<ObjectIntPair<String>> pairs = bag.topOccurrences(bag.sizeDistinct());
Assert.assertEquals(PrimitiveTuples.pair("o'clock", 3), pairs.getFirst());
Assert.assertEquals(PrimitiveTuples.pair("rock", 1), pairs.getLast());
System.out.println(pairs);
```

The output of this is:

```
[o'clock:3, two:1, one:1, three:1, rock:1]
```

While the value of the orders is sorted, when there are ties, there is no predictable order for the keys.  If you would like to have a predictable order for the keys, you can use a `SortedBag` instead.

```
Bag<String> bag =
    SortedBags.mutable.with("one o'clock two o'clock three o'clock rock".split(" "));
ListIterable<ObjectIntPair<String>> pairs = bag.topOccurrences(bag.sizeDistinct());
Assert.assertEquals(PrimitiveTuples.pair("o'clock", 3), pairs.getFirst());
Assert.assertEquals(PrimitiveTuples.pair("two", 1), pairs.getLast());
System.out.println(pairs);
```

The output of this is:

```
[o'clock:3, one:1, rock:1, three:1, two:1]
```

If you want to use the Pattern.splitAsStream as Brian suggested, then you can change the code as follows to work with Streams using `Collector.toCollection`:

```
Bag<String> bag =
    Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream("one o'clock two o'clock three o'clock rock")
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeBag::new));
ListIterable<ObjectIntPair<String>> pairs = bag.topOccurrences(bag.sizeDistinct());
Assert.assertEquals(PrimitiveTuples.pair("o'clock", 3), pairs.getFirst());
Assert.assertEquals(PrimitiveTuples.pair("two", 1), pairs.getLast());
System.out.println(pairs);
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.