# Can I limit Collectors.toMap() entries?

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I'm looking for a way to limit the number of entries produced by `Collectors.toMap()` with a merge function. Consider the following example:

```
Map<String, Integer> m = Stream.of("a", "a", "b", "c", "d")
    .limit(3)
    .collect(toMap(Function.identity(), s -> 1, Integer::sum));
```

The problem with the above is that I'll only have 2 elements in the resulting map (`a=2, b=1`). Is there any convenient way to short-circuit the stream once it's processed 3 *distinct* keys?

Comment: Can't you just filter?

Comment: Could you do something like this? Not sure if it's allowed. `Map<String, Integer> m = Stream.of("a", "a", "b", "c", "d")
    .limit(m.size() < 3 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : 3)
    .collect(toMap(Function.identity(), 1, Integer::sum));`

Comment: *"Is there a way?"* Yes, write your own `toMap()` collector. Is that *convenient*? Matter of perspective, I guess.

Comment: @Andreas Is it possible to write a short-circuiting collector? Do you mind posting an example?

Comment: I guess one problem could be that, once the point of 3 distinct keys is reached, there might still be remaining elements in the stream with the same key, that would not get added into the map. Or is that intended?

Comment: @JornVernee I'm not concerned about the remaining elements.

Comment: So... `["a", "a", "b", "a", "b"]` in your case should produce `{a->2, b->1}` or `{a->3, b->2}`?

Comment: @vsminkov `{a=3, b=2}` because the limit of 3 keys was never reached. If the limit is reached, it could stop immediately, though I don't mind merging consecutive duplicates either.

Comment: @shmosel is this what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441088/group-by-counting-in-java8-stream-api it's how to do a group and count using a stream. Sounds like the problem you are trying to tackle. Thought it doesn't limit the results

Comment: @Vld Not at all what I'm looking for. The counter is just demonstration of a merge function. Though I guess a similar question could be asked about `groupingBy()`.

Comment: @shmosel then you should truncate resulting map because you cannot guarantee that you collect all repeating values till iterate whole stream

Comment: No, you can't short-circuit collectors.

Comment: @vsminkov I said I don't care about subsequent duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution for this would be to write your own `Spliterator`, which would wrap the spliterator of a given `Stream`. This `Spliterator` would delegate the advancing calls to the wrapped spliterator and contain the logic of counting of many distinct elements have appeared.

For that, we can subclass `AbstractSpliterator` and provide our own `tryAdvance` logic. In the following, all elements encountered are added to a set. When the size of that set becomes greater than our maximum or when the wrapped spliterator has no remaining elements, we return `false` to indicate that there are no remaining elements to consider. This will stop when the numbers of distinct elements have been reached.

```
private static <T> Stream<T> distinctLimit(Stream<T> stream, int max) {
    Spliterator<T> spltr = stream.spliterator();
    Spliterator<T> res = new AbstractSpliterator<T>(spltr.estimateSize(), spltr.characteristics()) {

        private Set<T> distincts = new HashSet<>();
        private boolean stillGoing = true;

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
            boolean hasRemaining = spltr.tryAdvance(elem -> {
                distincts.add(elem);
                if (distincts.size() > max) {
                    stillGoing = false;
                } else {
                    action.accept(elem);
                }
            });
            return hasRemaining && stillGoing;
        }
    };
    return StreamSupport.stream(res, stream.isParallel()).onClose(stream::close);
}
```

With your example code, you would have:

```
Map<String, Long> m =
    distinctLimit(Stream.of("a", "a", "b", "c", "d"), 3)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

and the output would be the expected `{a=2, b=1, c=1}`, i.e. a map with 3 distinct keys.

Comment: Seems like it might be cleaner to use an `Iterator`.