# Count the same items in a row in Java 8 Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

I have a bean and a stream

```
public class TokenBag {
    private String token;
    private int count;
    // Standard constructor and getters here
}
Stream<String> src = Stream.of("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a");
```

and want to apply some intermediate operation to the stream that returns another stream of objects of TokenBag. In this example there must be two: ("a", 3), ("b", 3) and ("a", 2).

Please think it as a very simplistic example. In real there will be much more complicated logic than just counting the same values in a row. Actually I try to design a simple parser that accepts a stream of tokens and returns a stream of objects.

Also please note that it must stay a stream (with no intermediate accumulation), and also in this example it must really count the same values in a row (it differs from grouping).

Will appreciate your suggestions about the general approach to this task solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441088/group-by-counting-in-java-8-stream-api

Comment: Please think it as a very simplistic example. In real there will be much more complicated logic than just counting the same values in a row. Actually I try to design a simple parser that accepts a stream of tokens and returns a stream of objects.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your answers!... but just some more details. I need it to stay a stream (there must be no terminal operation at the end), and also in this example it must really count the same values (not grouping). So from "aaabbaa" in must return (a, 3), (b, 2) and (a, 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to convert your stream to a [`Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) and then adapt this spliterator to a custom one that *partially-reduces* some elements according to your logic (in your example it would need to count equal elements until a different element appears). Then, you'd need to turn your spliterator back to a new stream.

Bear in mind that this can't be 100% lazy, as you'd need to eagerly consume some elements from the backing stream in order to create a new `TokenBag` element for the new stream.

Here's the code for the custom spliterator:

```
public class CountingSpliterator
        extends Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<TokenBag>
        implements Consumer<String> {

    private final Spliterator<String> source;
    private String currentToken;
    private String previousToken;
    private int tokenCount = 0;
    private boolean tokenHasChanged;

    public CountingSpliterator(Spliterator<String> source) {
        super(source.estimateSize(), source.characteristics());
        this.source = source;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super TokenBag> action) {
        while (source.tryAdvance(this)) {
            if (tokenHasChanged) {
                action.accept(new TokenBag(previousToken, tokenCount));
                tokenCount = 1;
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (tokenCount > 0) {
            action.accept(new TokenBag(currentToken, tokenCount));
            tokenCount = 0;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(String newToken) {
        if (currentToken != null) {
            previousToken = currentToken;
        }
        currentToken = newToken;
        if (previousToken != null && !previousToken.equals(currentToken)) {
            tokenHasChanged = true;
        } else {
            tokenCount++;
            tokenHasChanged = false;
        }
    }
}
```

So this spliterator extends [`Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator.html) and also implements [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html). The code is quite complex, but the idea is that it adapts one or more tokens from the source spliterator into an instance of `TokenBag`.

For every accepted token from the source spliterator, the count for that token is incremented, until the token changes. At this point, a `TokenBag` instance is created with the token and the count and is immediately pushed to the `Consumer<? super TokenBag> action` parameter. Also, the counter is reset to `1`. The logic in the `accept` method handles token changes, border cases, etc.

Here's how you should use this spliterator:

```
Stream<String> src = Stream.of("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a");

Stream<TokenBag> stream = StreamSupport.stream(
        new CountingSpliterator(src.spliterator()),
        false); // false means sequential, we don't want parallel!

stream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you override `toString()` in `TokenBag`, the output is:

```
TokenBag{token='a', count=3}
TokenBag{token='b', count=2}
TokenBag{token='a', count=2}
```

A note on parallelism: I don't know how to parallelize this partial-reduce task, I even don't know if it's at all possible. But if it were, I doubt it would produce any measurable improvement.

Comment: Though too late but thank you, good answerer :) It works for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
Map<String, Long> result = src.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
System.out.println(result);
```

This will give the desired output

```
a=4, b=3
```

You can then go ahead and iterate over map and create objects of `TokenBag`.

Comment: under java-8 `Collectors.counting()` is worse than `Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)`

Answer (score 2):

```
    Stream<String> src = Stream.of("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b");

// collect to map 
    Map<String, Long> counted = src
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

// collect to list 
    List<TokenBag> tokenBags = counted.entrySet().stream().map(m -> new TokenBag(m.getKey(), m.getValue().intValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

First group it to a Map and then map the entries to a TokenBag:

```
Map<String, Long> values = src.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
List<TokenBag> tokenBags = values.entrySet().stream().map(entry -> {
    TokenBag tb = new TokenBag();
    tb.setToken(entry.getKey());
    tb.setCount(entry.getValue().intValue());
    return tb;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a map and then collect the map into the list:

```
Stream<String> src = Stream.of("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b");
Map<String, Long> m = src.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
m.entrySet().stream().map(e -> new TokenBag(e.getKey(), e.getValue().intValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: same comment as above...   
under java-8 `Collectors.counting()` is worse than `Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)`

Comment: @Eugene Is it really that bad to use `Collectors.counting()`? I ask because I've seen you and others claiming it shouldn't be used due to performance reasons, while we're talking about streams here (not precisely the peak of performance)...

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner it's not, just boxing, lots of it potentially. If you can do it better, why not?

Comment: @Eugene Well, I understand that boxing can happen a lot of times, but I'd really keep `Collectors.counting()` and wait for the fix instead of using `Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)`. It looks so ugly...

Comment: @Eugene Did not know that. Did not measure... How worse? Are there some benchmarks for that?

Comment: @St.Antario I did not measure, but that should be fairly trivial

Comment: @Eugene Actually `summingInt` ended up 3 times faster. The unclear thing is that `summingInt` produces much more garbage with allocation rate `1953.630` vs `739.281` `MB/sec` on my machine... Still not clear why it's faster.

Comment: @St.Antario sounds so good for an investigation, but zero time on my side to look at :( really sorry