# How to reduce a list into another list with java

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of Services, for sample:

```
public class Service {
   private long id;
   private String name;
   private BigDecimal value;
}

List<Service> services;
```

my user can add a lot of services, but I need to show a grouped services, If my user add 3 times the service with `id` 1, I need to show only one time but with a properties quantity

*** EDIT ***

I have this class:

```
public class ServicoCalculado implements Serializable{
    private Long idServico;
    private String nmServico;
    private BigDecimal vlBase = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    private BigDecimal vlTotal = BigDecimal.ZERO;
  // getters e setters
}
```

so my User can add a lot of services:

```
List< ServicoCalculado> services = new ArrayList<>();
services.add(new ServicoCalculado(1, 'name 1', 1,2);
services.add(new ServicoCalculado(1, 'name 1', 1,2);
services.add(new ServicoCalculado(1, 'name 1', 1,2);
services.add(new ServicoCalculado(2, 'name 2', 2,3);
services.add(new ServicoCalculado(3, 'name 3', 2,4);
```

So then I have a class to show in a grid:

```
public class ServicosVO {
    private Long idServico;
    private String nmServico;
    private BigDecimal vlBase;
    private BigDecimal total;
    private int qtd;
}
```

So I need to transform the  first List in a List of second

This is the output

idServico  ||  nmServico ||  vlBase || total || qtd

```
1       ||  name 1    ||     3   ||  6    ||  3 
2       ||  name 2    ||     2   ||  3    ||  1 
3       ||  name 3    ||     2   ||  4    ||  1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by counting in Java 8 stream API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441088/group-by-counting-in-java-8-stream-api)

Comment: For me, it is still unclear what the expected result is. Could you explain further?

Comment: problem is... which one will you show? they have the same ID, but what if they have different names> Or different values? I'm voting to close this as it is unclear

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map` instead of a list and set whatever you want to make unique as keys.

Answer (score 1):

here's another variant to getting a map of ids and a count of their occurrences:

```
services.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Service::getId, e -> 1, Math::addExact));
```

if you actually want to apply some merging logic in the case of a key collision and get back, as a result, a collection of services then use the [`toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) collector as follows:

```
Collection<Service> resultSet = services.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Service::getId, 
                       e -> new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(e)),
                       (l, r){ /* merging logic here */}).values();
```

Comment: You did some unnecessary acrobatics in the first code segment, the second one was in place (good). The first code segment is simply replaceable by `services.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Service::getId, Collectors.counting()))`.

Comment: @marsouf  I didn’t use groupingBy/counting as there is already an answer with that so I decided to take something else out my sleeves :-). Anyhow, after reading the post another few times I just think the OP might be after my second solution. I am not sure what you mean by unnecessary acrobatics?

Comment: @marsouf Right, might of just got what you mean and I think I’ve already answered that. That said, even though groupingBy with the counting downstream collector is more readable there is definitely more ways to accomplish the task in a compact and concise way hence my solution using toMap collector.

Comment: Agreed, hence my upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly:

```
 services.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
              Service::getId, 
              Collectors.counting()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a subclass of `Service`:

```
public class MultipleService extends Service{
    private long quantity;

    public MultipleService(Service service, long quantity){
        // assuming parent has a all arg constructor
        this(service.id, service.name, service.value);
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

And then reduce it into that:

```
List<MultipleService> list = services.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> new MultipleService(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> This answers assumes that `equals` and `hashcode` are properly overriden for `Service`