# Calculate the frequency of characters in a string (Java, Performance)

Tags: java, arrays, string, performance, char

#### Problem

I wrote this program to check the number of times that each letter appears in a string input by the user. It works fine, but is there a more efficient or alternative solutions of going about this task than reiterating through a twenty-six-element-long array for every single character?

#### Code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Letters {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[] c = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
        int[] f = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        System.out.println("Enter a string.");
        String k = sc.nextLine();
        String s = k.toUpperCase();
        s = s.trim();
        int l = s.length();
        System.out.println("Checking string = " + s);
        char ch;
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            ch = s.charAt(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
                if (ch == c[j]) {
                    f[j]++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Char\tFreq");
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            if (f[i] != 0) {
                System.out.println(c[i] + "\t" + f[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this question is more suitable for -> https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: One simple way is to use the Stream API. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441088/group-by-counting-in-java-8-stream-api).

Comment: You could use `f[ch - 'A']++` to avoid the inefficient iteration.

Comment: @Emma thanks for the tip. I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly initialize 26 entries in your frequency array (the default value is zero); you also don't need to keep the table of characters (it is sufficient to know the offset). That is, your code can eliminate `c` entirely and calculate each letter; like,

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] f = new int[26];
System.out.println("Enter a string.");
String orig = sc.nextLine();
String k = orig.trim().toUpperCase();
System.out.println("Checking string = " + orig);
for (char ch : k.toCharArray()) {
    f[ch - 'A']++;
}
System.out.println("Char\tFreq");
for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
    if (f[i] != 0) {
        System.out.println((char) ('A' + i) + "\t" + f[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the line for (char ch : k.toCharArray()) I've never seen a for loop's definition with that sort of construction (mine has always been initialization, condition and increment), so could you please clarify that for me?

Comment: @ArtemisHunter [`for-each`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work) `char ch` in the `char[]` returned from the `String k` by [`toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--)...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That clarifies it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the frequency of characters in a String by writing

```
String.length() - String.replace("character", "").length();
```

Answer (score 0):

You avoid the inner loop by using the fact that letters A-Z appear consecutively in ASCII. So, you don't have to search for the character in the array `c`, just compute the index. See code below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    char ch = s.charAt(i);
    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
        int j = (int)(ch - 'A'); // j will be in the range [0, 26)
        f[j]++;
    } 
}
```

We can get rid of the array `c` also similarly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    if (f[i] != 0) {
        System.out.println((char)('A' + i) + "\t" + f[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, it's essentially confirming that the character is a letter and then using its ASCII code to refer to the corresponding index? I'm still a little confused as to (ch - 'A')'s working.

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. (ch-'A') basically takes the ASCII (Actually UTF16, but for english letters they are the same) and subtract the ASCII of 'A' giving you the index. 

Btw, @ElliottFrisch's code above doesn't check that the char is A-Z, so if there is a non-letter character in the input, it will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

If we have strings like "romeo@alphacharlie.com", then the example having freqArr[c - 'A']++ will not work. You can try using this.

```
private static int[] decodeFrequency(char[] array) {
    int[] freqArr = new int[127];
    for ( char c : array ) {
        freqArr[(int)c]++;
    }
    return freqArr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out. I haven't understood why there's a necessity for the array to have a length of 127 though (aren't there only 26 letters in the alphabet?). It would be great if you could explain that.

Comment: I have used the entire ASCII table length. https://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap4/subsection2.1.1.1.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve the problem, I would encourage you to follow one which you understand easily. My solution below basically initializes an array of 26 to count the frequency of all the characters.

### Important part :

Every alphabet will have a ASCII value so, by typecasting you eventually get the integer value and then by subtracting 65 **(For Upper Case alphabets)** you will get the index of the array to store the frequency of respective character.

> Your Modified Java Code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Letters{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] f = new int[26];
        System.out.println("Enter a string.");
        String k = sc.nextLine();
        String s = k.toUpperCase();
        s = s.trim();
        int l = s.length();
        System.out.println("Checking string = " + s);
        char ch;
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            ch = s.charAt(i);

            //This will give the ASCII value of the character i.e. ch
            int temp=(int)ch;
            if(temp>=65 && temp<=90){
              //subtract 65 to get index 
              //add 1 to increase frequency 
              f[temp - 65]+=1;
            }
            
        }
        System.out.println("Char\tFreq");
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            if (f[i] != 0) {
                //Add 65 to get respective character
                System.out.println((char)(i+65) + "\t" + f[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Eg:**

f[0] for 'A'

f[1] for 'B'

....

f[25] for 'Z'

**(Remember index start from 0)**

This way you can eliminate inner for loop and get frequency with single integer array.

Comment: Java uses UTF-16, not ASCII. (Your algorithm happens to be equally valid for the characters in question, though.) And, `'A'` is much preferred to 65, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String str="hsysnkkajffaf";
        Map<Character,Integer> map=new HashMap();

        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
            char c=str.charAt(i);
            if(map.containsKey(c))
                map.put(c,map.get(c)+1);
            else
                map.put(c,1);
        }

        for(Map.Entry<Character,Integer> e:map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```