# Java 8 stream sort by maximum duplicates and then distinct

Tags: java, java-stream

Using a stream, how to sort a list of objects by field  (in my case ,`componentCode`) that has the maximum number of duplicates, and then find distinct

I tried something like this, but how to add the size of the duplicates when sorting.

```
List<String> conflictingComponentsCode = componentWarnings.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ComponentErrorDetail::getComponentCode))
    .map(ComponentErrorDetail::getComponentCode)
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please replace your (largely unhelpful) screenshot with simple data examples entered as text, and eliminate irrlelevant fields (such as "concentration", "errorDesc", etc)

Comment: I think you are looking for this (see section 1.2) https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-collectors-groupingby-and-mapping-example/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very similar to @nafas option:

```
List<String> conflictingComponentsCode = componentWarnings.stream()
    .map(ComponentErrorDetail::getComponentCode)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())) 
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can check this question for another example of grouping by count: [Group by counting in Java 8 stream API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441088/group-by-counting-in-java-8-stream-api)

Comment: Instead of `.map(ComponentErrorDetail::getComponentCode) .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))`, you can simply use `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ComponentErrorDetail::getComponentCode, Collectors.counting()))`

Answer (score 2):

the idea is to use `Collectors.groupingBy` function to make a map (value to count), then sort the map in reverse order then map back to list again.

here a rough implementation:

```
List<String> conflictingComponentsCode = 
componentWarnings.stream()
    .map(ComponentErrorDetail::getComponentCode).collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())
        ) 
    //sort map
    .entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue()
             .reversed())

    //map to list
   .map(entry -> entry.key()).collect(Collectors.toList());
;
```

Comment: [forEachOrdered](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEachOrdered-java.util.function.Consumer-) is a [terminal operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) - this will throw when you try to call `entrySet` the second time.

Comment: Actually, the problem isn't that it's a terminal operation (`collect(...)` is too and that's fine), the problem is that `forEachOrdered(...)` has a **`void`** return type.

Comment: @Andreas `collect` returns a value - the reason it seems ok here is that all further operations are called on the return value. In truth, the stream generated by `componentWarnings::stream` can no longer be operated on, the moment that `collect` is called.

Comment: @Avi I know. My point is that the issue with this code is not that `forEachOrdered` is *terminal*, but that it is `void`. I used `collect` as an example that a terminal operation is fine in a method chain like this. It's having a `void` method that breaks the chain, not having a *terminal* operation.

Comment: @Andreas the problem with this code is the `void` return type of `forEachOrdered` **and** the `finalMap` appearing out of nowhere. Besides the point that this collecting this sorted stream into a map, just to stream again over it, before collecting into the final list, is entirely obsolete.

Comment: thanks, guys, that's what happens when I don't run my codes. I think its fixed now