# How to access the map Collecters.toMap is collecting to?

Tags: java, functional-programming

```
collect(Collectors.toMap(String::toString, str -> {map.get(str)+1})
```

I want to maintain counts of strings in a map. Is there anyway to access the map the Collector is collecting into?

Comment: No. But you can write your own collector with your own Map.

Comment: That looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). I am guessing you probably wanted to know how to [Group by counting in Java 8 stream API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25441088)

Answer (score 3):

You can try to make something like this :

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("red", "blue", "green");
Map<String, Integer> map1 = list1.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(String::toString, t -> t.length()));
```

But if you have a duplicate value in your list you should merge them :

```
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("red", "red", "blue", "green");
Map<String, Integer> map2 = list2.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(String::toString, t -> t.length(), (line1, line2) -> line1));
```

And, if you want to make your code more efficient you can use a parallel stream with concurrent map
but you have to ensure that you don't have a null value (for more information about the concurrent map you refer to the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html))

```
List<String> list3 = Arrays.asList("red", "red", "blue", "green", null);
Map<String, Integer> map3 = list3.parallelStream()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(String::toString, t -> t.length(), (line1, line2) -> line1));
```

I hope this is useful to you ;)